# MS Access SQL UPDATE using multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, where-clause

I am trying to update Table 1 using values from Table 2 and Table 3. There is no relation field between Table 1 and (Tables 2 and 3) so I am using a conditional WHERE Statement. I only want to pull CF from table 3 when the table3.TOS is 7 and pull the region portion from table2.stateID when table1.zip is between or equal to the start/end zip codes in table 2. Table 2 and 3 relate on a stateID field.

This code seems to work but when run Access says updating 5880 rows despite Table 1 only having 1471 rows. I am wondering what in my code is causing this number to be so inflated and when I run it, the tables look good with correct numbers. Again THIS CODE RUNS AS-IS but tells me it is updating way more rows than expected.

```
    UPDATE table1, table2, table3
    SET table1.region = '00' + right(table2.[stateID],2),
    table1.cf = table3.cf,
    table1.eff_date = '2020-03-01'
    WHERE (table3.[TOS] = '7' AND table2.[stateID] = table3.[stateID])
    AND (table1.[zip] = table2.[zip_start] 
    OR table1.[zip] = table2.[zip_end] 
    OR (table1.[zip] BETWEEN table2.[zip_start] AND table2.[zip_end]));
```

Comment: Remove Update and replace with Select *. This will give 5880 rows and you will see what is wrong with your join. It's possible that table1 has the State column and you need to include it in the join.

Comment: Oh I see when I did the select * for all three and filtered for a single zip, there appears to be duplicates but there are other fields in table 3 that have differences so I need to condense the join

Comment: Martin the update is operating on roughly 4X the original number of rows. You should post your own answer once you sort it out.

Comment: It may be possible to achieve what you need using an update join on a derived table instead of table3. select the distinct combinations of State and TOS to get the required number of updates. See for similar: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/is-it-possible-to-join-derived-tables-to-actual-in-access-2007

Comment: That's what I am thinking, just create a derived table from table 3 that has the distinct values I need and join on that

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE table3.[TOS] = '7' AND
      table2.[stateID] = table3.[stateID] AND
      table1.[zip] BETWEEN table2.[zip_start] AND table2.[zip_end];
```

I wonder if MS Access is reporting multiple updates on the same row.

Comment: I can definitely condense the WHERE clause, issue I am running into is with table 3. Basically a StateID with TOS '7' returns various rows because there are differences in other fields I would like to ignore in the join.

Comment: So when I run a `SELECT DISTINCT cf, stateID from table3 INNER JOIN table1 ON left(table3.stateID,2) = table1.state WHERE table3.TOS = "7"` I get the values I want to use but not sure how to control for that distinct in an update